# Spring Boot - Using JWT, OAuth, and Separate Resource and Auth Servers

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I am attempting to build a Spring application that uses JWT tokens and the OAuth2 protocol. I have the Authentication Server running thanks to [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@nydiarra/secure-a-spring-boot-rest-api-with-json-web-token-reference-to-angular-integration-e57a25806c50). However, I am struggling with getting the Resource Server to function properly. From following the article, and thanks to a response to a [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48084965/spring-oauth2-with-jwt-cannot-convert-access-token-to-json-when-separating-aut/48088156#48088156), this is my current attempt:

Security config for Resource Server:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${security.signing-key}")
    private String signingKey;

    @Value("${security.encoding-strength}")
    private Integer clientID;

    @Value("${security.security-realm}")
    private String securityRealm;

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setVerifierKey(signingKey);
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean ResourceServerTokenServices tokenService() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthenticationManager authManager = new OAuth2AuthenticationManager();
        authManager.setTokenServices(tokenService());
        return authManager;
    }

}
```

Resource Server config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private ResourceServerTokenServices tokenServices;

@Value("${security.jwt.resource-ids}")
private String resourceIds;

@Override
public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
    resources.resourceId(resourceIds).tokenServices(tokenServices);
}

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.requestMatchers().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/actuator/**", "/api-docs/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").authenticated();
}
```

}

Security config for Authorization Server (from noted tutorial):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${security.signing-key}")
    private String signingKey;

    @Value("${security.encoding-strength}")
    private Integer encodingStrength;

    @Value("${security.security-realm}")
    private String securityRealm;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(new ShaPasswordEncoder(encodingStrength));
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .realmName(securityRealm)
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable();

    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey(signingKey);
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary //Making this primary to avoid any accidental duplication with another token service instance of the same name
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }
}
```

Now, when I attempt to make a request to the Resource server, I receive an error such as follows:

`{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Invalid access token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOlsidGVzdGp3dHJlc291cmNlaWQiXSwidXNlcl9uYW1lIjoiam9obi5kb2UiLCJzY29wZSI6WyJyZWFkIiwid3JpdGUiXSwiZXh
wIjoxNTE1MTE3NTU4LCJhdXRob3JpdGllcyI6WyJTVEFOREFSRF"}`

I have a couple questions:

- To my understanding, the issue is often associated with token stores. How does one handle separting the servers when a JwtTokenStore is used?
- Second, currently, my Resource app relies on having access to a key. To my understanding of the JWT and 0Auth specs, this should not be necessary. Rather, I should be able to delegate the validation to the Authentication server itself. From the Spring docs, I thought the following property might be applicable `security.oauth2.resource.token-info-uri=http://localhost:8080/oauth/check_token`. However, if I attempt to not rely on a key with my Resource Server, then I run into difficulties setting my  ResourceServerTokenService. The service expects a token store, the JWTTokenStore uses a JwtAccessTokenConverter, and the converter uses a key (removing the key resulted in the same `invalid token` error I experienced earlier).

I am really struggling to find articles that show how to separate the Auth and Resource server. Any advice would be appreciated.

EDIT:
Actually, the code for the Resource Server is now failing to compile with the following message:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: For MAC signing you do not need to specify the verifier key separately, and if you do it must match the signing key`

Comment: Hi Kelly, I am attempting the same thing, what class do i need to split out into the authentication and resource server? Thanks

Comment: @seanie_oc, it would depend on your application and how it is currently structured. I had two separate Spring boot apps. One had a `@Configuration` class annotated with `@EnableResourceServer` and extending `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`. The other had a`@Configuration` class annotated with `@EnableAuthorizationServer` and extending `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter`. The tutorial noted in the opening post provides some very useful information for getting started. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the tips I followed the same tutorial that you mentioned at the beginning but am a little confused on what goes where

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried spring oauth and I came across the same error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: For MAC signing you do not need to specify the verifier key separately, and if you do it must match the signing key
```

My mistake was that my public certificate was :

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
tadadada
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
tadadada
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

And this is not allowed. REMOVE the certificate, just let the public key in this file :

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
tadadada
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

And the startup error will disapear.

For your second question, that's what I understand :

- The authentication server give you an encrypted token (encrypted with the private key), that contains ALL the permissions of your user.
- The resource server decrypts the token with the public key, and assumes that the permissions contained in the token are TRUE.

Hopes this help.

Comment: Thanks much. I recall that I actually made a similar mistake, except I removed the --BEGIN PUBLIC KEY -- and -- END PUBLIC KEY -- lines. For anyone who stumbles across this issue, as noted by @Oreste Viron, you need to remove the certificate portion, but actually keep the -- --- lines that contain the public key.

Comment: Thanks. I omitted the -- label for both private and public key. I thought they were not needed

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue, when my public key was formatted as below:

```
"-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n${encoder.encodeToString(keyPair.public.encoded)}\n-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
```

When I changed this to:

```
"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n${encoder.encodeToString(keyPair.public.encoded)}\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
```

The key was accepted.

Comment: This is not helpful at all. How did you change your code? I have no public keys in my JWT code but I get this error

Comment: Late reply - but hopefully it helps someone else. In our case - we exposed our own public key endpoint. The example above is the public key - which @ResourceServer annotated spring projects can read (from a rest endpoint in my case).

Hope that helps.