# Spring Boot OAuth 2 Resource Server not accepting public key for JWT verification

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using Spring Boot 2.1.5 and creating two separate modules for Authorization Server and Resource Server. I recently shifted to use JWT instead of normal access tokens using the examples shown [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt) and [here](http://stytex.de/blog/2016/02/01/spring-cloud-security-with-oauth2/).

Now the error which got me here is this

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: For MAC signing you do not need to specify the verifier key separately, and if you do it must match the signing key
```

I had a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48213780/3733631) but that's not the case with me. I have generated proper files using keytool and saved them to my resources folder.

1. JKS file in the resources folder of Authorization Server module
2. public_key.txt in the resources folder of Resource Server module

Here is my Authorization Server Configuration File

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthorizationServerConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public void configure(final ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(this.dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(
                Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer(), jwtAccessTokenConverter()));

        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
                .accessTokenConverter(jwtAccessTokenConverter())
                .tokenStore(tokenStore());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) {
        oauthServer.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder).tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(jwtAccessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();

        KeyStoreKeyFactory keyStoreKeyFactory =
                new KeyStoreKeyFactory(new ClassPathResource("accesstoken_keystore.jks"), "my-keystore-password".toCharArray());
        jwtAccessTokenConverter.setKeyPair(keyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair("my-alias"));
        return jwtAccessTokenConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
        return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices(final TokenStore tokenStore,
                                              final ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService) {
        DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        tokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        tokenServices.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        tokenServices.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        return tokenServices;
    }
}
```

And Here is my Resource Server Configuration class

```java
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ResourceServerConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private CustomAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer config) {
        config.tokenServices(tokenServices());
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();

        Resource publicKeyResource = new ClassPathResource("public_key.txt");
        String publicKey = null;
        try {
            publicKey = new String(FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(publicKeyResource.getInputStream()));
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        converter.setVerifierKey(publicKey);  //this is where I'm getting the error

        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }
```

And here is the content of public_key.txt file as it is

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I'm expecting that the Authorization Server will sign the JWT using the Private Key extracted from the KeyStore file and Resource Server will just verify it.

Not sure what's wrong. Everything was working fine before I decided to use a RSA key asymmetric pair.

Comment: Did you find the solution for the issue. If yes, please post here as an answer